# Haskell about how to separate the last number from a string number

Tags: haskell

I have a question about haskell in seperation the last number from a string number. For example, input is (1234), output is (123,4) 
I have done a programming, but it does not work.

```
toDigits :: Int -> [Int]
toDigits n
 | n <= 0        = []
 | otherwise     = toDigits(n `mod` 10) ++ [n `div` 10]
```

Comment: Often the code we write doesn't work (or compile) on the first try. Useful things to do are: test short pieces of your code in ghci (and ask their type with `:t`), trace the execution of your function with pen and paper, compile with `-Wall`. In your case I'd suggest the pen-and-paper approach. Also you probably want `toDigits :: Int -> Maybe (Int, Int)`

Comment: Your recursion/termination is broken, so think through the algorithm again.  Take the number '1' for example.  `mod 1 10 == 1` so you will infinitely call `toDigits` because you will never reach zero.

Comment: @jberryman Why not `Int -> (Int, Int)`? I can't picture an `Int` value that I would map to `Nothing` given this algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You just have `div` and `mod` swapped.

```
toDigits n | n <= 0 = []
           | otherwise = toDigits (n `div` 10) ++ [n `mod` 10]
```

Comment: That fixed his function but his request seemed to be asking for `f :: Int -> (Int,Int)`, perhaps `f x = (x \`div\` 10, x \`mod\` 10)`.

Comment: Possibly, although that's a really boring question: `f x = divMod x 10`.